# How to bind viewModel property in a ResourceDictionary

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, resourcedictionary

I have the static resource named ArticoliDTSelector defined in the ResourceDictionary and I need to bind the property MostraGriglia to a value which is in the viewModel.
But, when I try to run, I get following error: "No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "MostraGriglia", or mismatching type between value and property."
Why can't the compiler find the property CatalogoVisualizzato?

I try to bind like so:

```
    <base:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:base="clr-namespace:Vendo.Views"
           xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Vendo.Models"        
           xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Vendo.ViewModels"  
           x:DataType="viewmodels:DettaglioArticoliViewModel"               
           xmlns:selector="clr-namespace:Vendo.DataTemplatesSelector" >

<base:BasePage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GridLinearList">
            <!--foo-->
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="GridImages">
            <!--foo-->
        </DataTemplate>

        <selector:ArticoliDTSelector x:Key="ArticoliTemplateSelector"                                            
                                MostraGriglia="{Binding CatalogoVisualizzato, Source={StaticResource viewmodels:DettaglioArticoliViewModel}}"
                                ElencoTemplate="{StaticResource GridLinearList}"
                                GrigliaTemplate="{StaticResource GridImages}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</base:BasePage.Resources>
</base:BasePage>
```

DataTemplateSelector class implementation:

```
    internal class ArticoliDTSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ElencoTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate GrigliaTemplate { get; set; }

    public bool MostraGriglia { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        if (MostraGriglia)
            return GrigliaTemplate;
        else
            return ElencoTemplate;
    }
}
```

ViewModel implementation:

```
    class DettaglioArticoliViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    static bool catalogoVisualizzato;        
    public bool CatalogoVisualizzato
    {
        get => catalogoVisualizzato;
        set => SetProperty(ref catalogoVisualizzato, value);
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can cheak the [Resource dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries?view=net-maui-7.0) for more information.

Comment: Thk, but I have not found anything of interesting about my issue.

Comment: Actually, the Resource dictionaries use the StaticResource and the viewmodel can not bind the data to the Resource dictionaries. You can read the [ResourceDictionary and XAML resource references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-resource-dictionary)